How do I identify the root cause of Invalid resource ID 0x00000000 in Android Studio LogCat
This question is for Android apps targeting Android SDK 34 (i.e. the latest SDK version for Android 14).  Whenever I launch the Settings screen, I got these errors multiple times in the log:
E  Invalid resource ID 0x00000000.
E  Invalid resource ID 0x00000000.
E  Invalid resource ID 0x00000000.
E  Invalid resource ID 0x00000000.
E  Invalid resource ID 0x00000000.
E  Invalid resource ID 0x00000000.
The Settings screen consists of an Activity and a Fragment. The Activity extends AppCompatActivity, and the Fragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat.  There are also the XML file for the Activity, and the XML file for the Fragment.  The overall design is typical.  I followed the standard approach by this official Google site: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/settings
It is so strange that the error only appears when the physical device (with Android 14) is used for testing. The same error does not appear in emulators or an older physical device.
The problem did NOT occur in the past.  It only started to occur recently when I was updating the app by targeting Android SDK 34.
Could someone let me know how to identify the root cause, and/or the solution?
Update:
I noticed that after restarting the physical device (with Android 14), the invalid resource ID error wouldn't appear in LogCat for several rounds of test.  After I unplugged and replugged the USB cable, the error appeared again.

can you post code of your activity?

Where's the complete stack trace ?

I noticed the same issue.  I found some of the problems relate to image loading failure with Glide or Coil (I transitioned to Coil). I ensured handling the errors and the the errors went away.  But I still have the issue when I open the Settings which doesn't load any images. Not sure what happens there.  And, only on my Samsung S21 Android 14

In my case, I see this error and I get tome System UI app crashed messages, but when I install it in my physical device this doesn't happen
